# bundling executable and shared libraries in linux

Tags: linux, virtualization, resourcebundle

I want to distribute my solution containing executable and dynamic and static libraries to client in a single package. I have found a solution for windows as of app virtualization using enigma virtualbox or thinapp. But I could not find any for linux. help me with any solutions for linux or any better solutions are welcome.

I found a result [to bundle all the files in tar and run .exe using script shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46478/join-the-executable-and-all-its-libraries) but it is accessible to the client, which my company don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [FlatPak](https://flatpak.org/) it bundles all the dynamic libraries so that it does not depend to system.

Comment: Is there any application with which I have a privilege to not share my code but only can run the build application standalone as an executable.

Comment: It depends on your programming language but essentially they will have a binary which can be reversed into a set of assembly code and even nice C code in some cases